# preventDefault() causing a submitted form to redirect to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a product page with the following form:

```
<form id="ratingsForm" action='../resources/add_rating_to_product.php' method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="productID" value="<?php echo $productID; ?>" />
    <span class="rating">
        <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
                    id="rating-input-1-5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
        ...
        <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
                    id="rating-input-1-1" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
    </span>
</form>
```

This is just a simple star rating form which uses radio buttons.
I have a javascript file that will submit the form once a radio button is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('input[name=rating]').change(function(){
          $('form').submit();
     });
});
```

I have another javascript file that will trigger when the form is submitted and use ajax to post it to the correct file.

```
$(document).ready( function() { 

    $("#ratingsForm").on("submit",function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( response ) {
                alert('Thanks for rating');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Add_rating_to_product just takes the posted information and inserts it into the database.

The problem I'm having is that instead of preventing and redirection, `e.preventDefault` redirects me to my search page for apparently no reason. I have check all of my code in my product page and there's nothing that could redirect me there so what is the problem? Without the `preventDefault()`, it redirects to `add_rating_to_product.php` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance you have another form on your page? If you do, the following code submits all the forms on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('input[name=rating]').change(function(){
          $('form').submit();
     });
});
```

I think it would be safer to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('input[name=rating]').change(function(){
          $(this).closest('form').submit();
     });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After the success function call you can use

```
 $(this).unbind('submit').submit()
```

, which will allow the execution to continue as if preventDefault was nt called

Comment: @aldrin27   The action will decide where to send the user to and with in that php file, it can send the user to anywhere they want to go with a php redirect.

header('Location: someting.php');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('input[name=rating]').change(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

       var prodID = $(this).find("input[name='productID']").val();

       $.ajax( {

        type: "POST",
        url: $(form#ratingsForm).attr( 'action' ),
        data: {$('form#ratingsForm').serialize(), prodID: prodID},
        success: function( response ) {
           alert('Thanks for rating');
        }          
       });
    });
 });
```

Just do it in one function to initialize and send them in server side. I hope this works.

Comment: But with that method wouldn't the productID not be posted? How would I work around that?

Comment: It would get in the server because it's in inside the form

Comment: I just tried it and serialize is now only getting the value of the input and not the product id anymore.